# Both named and dnsmasq serving DNS on port 53?

Tags: networking, dns, bind, dnsmasq

Is this considered normal for Ubuntu 14.04 ?

`netstat -tulpn` shows that both bind9 (named) and dnsmasq serve on port 53:

```
 Active Internet connections (only servers) Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local
 Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4041/named 
 tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3653/dnsmasq
```

Also with UDP:

```
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*    4041/named
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*    3653/dnsmasq
```

Notice that only dnsmasq listens outside localhost, over port 67:

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           2158/dnsmasq
```

Other functions this server performs are primary DNS zones for a dev team's private domain, routing, NAT and transparent proxy(squid3 & iptables) with DHCP server.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is the machine working the way it should?

Comment: This is exactly my question. No, not all seems necessarily to be working "as it should"; this is one of many attack angles to eliminate info unrelated to other issues. For instance, XEN bridging side effects, VPN vs. LAN routing, etc.

Comment: Not knowing the specific requirements and issues it is difficult to establish what (if anything), is wrong with this setup. An obvious thing that comes to mind is: reduce the number of moving parts by taking out the bind server and have `dnsmasq` do the local DNS serving, and have it forward recursive queries to an upstream resolver. OTOH, if this ain't broke, why fix it? I don't think bind will be interfering with your routing. It is only a name server after all.

Comment: @zwets Generally, it is certainly not normal for services to be running on the same port, let alone at the same time, from the same host (including the recent 127.0.1.1 invention), on an out-of-the-box installation.  This is also a DNS question. How, for example, can DNS zones be served to the public if bind9(the one with the actual zone records) is not listening on 0.0.0.0? How does Ubuntu canonical reconcile this?

Comment: This is exactly why my first comment was: what exactly is your question? You asked whether this setup is _normal_ and I pointed out that what is normal depends on the requirements for the system. There may be legitimate reasons for running both bind9 and dnsmasq on a system. However, your now point out that you are referring to an _out of the box_ installation. So your question really is "Does an Ubuntu 14.04 installation include both bind9 and dnsmasq by default?" If you [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/524282/edit) to make that clear, you may get a better answer.

Comment: As for me, I can't give you a conclusive answer since my 14.04 servers are 12.04 upgrades. Several run bind9 because I installed that on them, none of them ran either bind9 or dnsmasq out of the box. However, this may be different for an OOtB 14.04 installation.

Comment: Also, please [open a separate question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) about the DNS servers listening on the `localhost` interfaces only and _yet_ serving a public network. Mystifying stuff.

Answer (score 0):

They are bound at different addresses. `named` is listening on `127.0.0.1` while `dnsmasq` is listening on `127.0.1.1`. They probably resolve to different virtual network devices